# Массив заполненный случайными значениями и подсчитать количество пар соседних элементов, имеющих противоположные знаки

Tags: c++

Полное задание: код для реализации заполнения ряд случайными значениями (от –50 до
50) и разработки функции, выполняющей такую ​​обработку символьного
строки: Подсчитать количество пар соседних элементов, имеющих
противоположные знаки. При реализации функции запрещается
пользоваться функциями библиотек языка C++

Я сделал это задание, используя функции библиотек. Сейчас нуждаюсь в помощи реализации этого кода без использования функций библиотек С++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    const int N = 10;

    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); SetConsoleCP(1251);
        srand(time(NULL));
        cout << "Массив " << endl;
        int arr[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
            cout << arr[i] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
        {
            if((arr[i]>=0 && arr[i+1]<=0) || (arr[i]<=0 && arr[i+1]>=0))
        count++;
        }
        cout << endl << "Кол-во = " << count << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Собственно, без **каких** функций? У вас они и не используются. Конечно, код можно написать и короче, но это в данном случае ни при чем...

Comment: В случайный массив не попадёт значение `50`.

Comment: Код сравнения считает два нуля двумя значениями разных знаков. В целом обработка нулей сомнительная.